# Tar: is there a way to exclude directories whose name match a given regex?

Tags: tar

More specifically, I have a workspace directory containing several coding projects, which in turn contain `node_module` directories. I want to create a `tar.gz` of my workspace while excluding all node_module directories, but when I try something like:

```
tar -cvzf projects.tar.gz projects/ --exclude="node_modules"
```

It does not exclude any of the `node_modules` subdirectories. Is there a way to do this?

Thank your for your help

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* Your question may be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or for the [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Anyway `--exclude=**/node_modules` (with the `globstar` option set in bash) should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but unfortunately it does not work either